# Why does <br> make a new line and \n fails to in JS

Tags: javascript, html, output, newline

I am coding a simple javascript program, and I found that when I use `\n` in the `document.write("");`, it doesn't make a new line. When I use the <`br`> tag it works.

I want to know *why* `\n` fails to make a new line and <`br`> makes one.

**Note:** I am completely new to Javascript...

My Javascript using **br**:

```
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Foo App</h1>

<script charset="utf-8">
  var input = null;

        input = prompt("Enter something: ");

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.write("Your input: " + input + "<br><br>");
        }
</script>
</body>
```

Output:

[image]

My javascript using `\n`:

```
<body>
    <h1>Foo App</h1>

<script charset="utf-8">
  var input = null;

        input = prompt("Enter something: ");

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.write("Your input: " + input + "\n\n");
        }
</script>
</body>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript, this is just how html works.

Comment: Ok, but I would like to know why it does that..

Comment: Because the document.write() function writes HTML into the element

Comment: Different with this condition, : console.log('iam\nprogrammer') . Thats write javascript, not html (for example)

Comment: and because HTML doesn't consider line breaks in the *code* to be line breaks in the *display*, as it'd mean you couldn't use line breaks to organize your code

Comment: `\n` is just ignored as whitespace, you will see them when viewing source though

Comment: \n is not markup, it's a character. If you want to see \n break a line, wrap your output in a preformatted tag. (<pre>First line\nSecond line\nThirdline</pre>

Comment: Yep, adding <pre> around the output with \n did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.write()` writes a block of HTML. And in HTML, `<br>` creates a new line. Therefore, if you want to create a new line when using `document.write()`, you will have to use `<BR>`

Answer (score 1):

`Document.write` creates HTML markup, not plain text. In HTML, a new line is represented by a `<br/>` element. If you were writing to the browser console, you would not be creating HTML markup, so the newline character "\n" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As @mrid says, when you use `document.write('HTML AS STRING')` is for writing HTML code as string, so when you use a `\n` is not a HTML entity, so you can use `<br>` html tag for writing a new line or use a entity html code as `&NewLine;` into your code.

Check the official list of [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for a quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-GB"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<style> body { white-space: pre-wrap; } 
</style> 
</head>
```

The style white-space: pre-wrap will show up the '\n'’s as newlines. This is the way HTML works it is not a problem with the JavaScript.